# Running regexp on the same variable twice

Tags: regex, perl

How can I run regexp more times on same variable?
I want

```
$$contRef =~ /Kurs.*?(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi;
```

and

```
 $$contRef =~ /Price(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi;
```

IIRC regexp sets a pointer and If I want to find any pattern again and start from the beginning I need to reset the variable. I don't want to copy the content to other variable.
I wish to reset the pointer to be able to start the searching from the beginning.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to find some pattern (and get in in $1) and then I want to find another pattern again. In the same content(in the same variable).

Comment: What, exactly, have you tried, and what problems are you having?

Comment: can you maybe use a pipe char `|` to separate the two matches? e.g. `$$contRef =~ /Kurs.*?(\d+,?\d*)<\/span|Price(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi;`

Comment: The counter you're thinking of only happens when dealing with the exact same pattern.  I.e. in a while loop:  `while ( $$contRef =~ /Kurs.*?(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi ) { ... do stuff }`. That doesn't seem to be your situation, so that doesn't matter here.  If it is, you need to explain a lot more...

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is exactly what you just pasted.

```
$$contRef =~ /Kurs.*?(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi;  
# Do stuff with $1
# ...
# ...
$$contRef =~ /Price(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi;
# Do new stuff with the new $1
# ...
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your unusual use of variables is the problem?  This works and prints 9922

```
$a="Kursplat99</spanPrice22</span";

$contRef = "a";

$$contRef =~ /Kurs.*?(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi;  

print $1;

$$contRef =~ /Price(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi;

print $1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested in the comments, perhaps a `while`, alternation (`|`) and an array for the captures would be helpful here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = "Kursplat99</span>Price22</span";
my @array;

push @array, $1 while $string =~ /(?:Kurs.*?|Price)(\d+,?\d*)<\/span/msgi;
print Dumper \@array if @array;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '99',
          '22'
        ];
```